# How to access parent in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am using ConstraintLayout to create a view programmatically and I want to set my button view `topTotop` of parent and `leftToleft` of the parent. How can I do that?

My code is below:

```
Button button = new Button(MainActivity.this);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(widthInt, heightInt);

params.topToTop =  // I want to set it parent
params.leftToLeft = // I want to set it parent
params.setMargins(marginStartint , marginTopInt , 0 , 0);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [PARENT_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams#PARENT_ID)

so your code becomes

```
params.topToTop = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
params.leftToLeft = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ConstraintSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html)'s [Connect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html#connect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method to perform such operations. There [PARENT_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html#PARENT_ID) to refer parent id.

```
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout)fndViewById(R.id.mainConstraint);
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.clone(layout);
set.connect(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
//view refers to the view's constraint to be changed
set.applyTo(layout);
```

> connect
>
> void connect (int startID, 
>                   int startSide, 
>                   int endID, 
>                   int endSide, 
>                   int margin)
>
> Create a constraint between two widgets.